# Primefaces conditional tooltip

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<p:spinner id="amount" 
           min="0" 
           max="#{bean.availableAmount}" 
           value="#{bean.amount}" />
<p:tooltip for="amount" 
           showEvent="focus" 
           hideEvent="blur" 
           disabled="#{bean.amount lt bean.maxAmount}" 
           value="Maximum amount has been reached" />
```

I'm looking for a way to implement something like the disabled property on above example. In other words, I'd like to implement a conditional tooltip that only shows IF the condition is met. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `rendered` instead of `disabled`? In that case you need to update the `p:tooltip` element, when the `p:spinner` changes its value. Use the [ajax spinner](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/spinner.jsf) from the Primefaces showcase:

```
<p:spinner id="amount" min="0" max="#{bean.availableAmount}" value="#{bean.amount}">  
  <p:ajax update="tooltip" process="@this" />  
</p:spinner>

<p:tooltip id="tooltip"
           for="amount" 
           showEvent="focus" 
           hideEvent="blur" 
           rendered="#{bean.amount lt bean.maxAmount}" 
           value="Maximum amount has been reached" />
```

**Update** (after reading your comments):

If you want to hide the tooltip, you can give the command to execute javascript code from the server side, when the response comes back to the browser:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("hideTooltip();");
```

which then calls `hideTooltip` in your javscript code:

```
function hideTooltip() {
  $("tooltip").hide();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach. Though the `hide` hasn't occurred yet which means the tooltip won't hide when `rendered="false"`

Comment: I've searched for a Javscript way to disable the tooltip upon `onsuccess` of `p:ajax`, but couldn't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this on client side by using tooltip's widget:

```
<p:spinner id="amount" min="0" max="#{bean.availableAmount}" value="#{bean.amount}">  
  <p:ajax oncomplete="myTooltip.hide()" process="@this" />  
</p:spinner>

<p:tooltip id="tooltip"
       for="amount" 
       showEvent="focus" 
       hideEvent="blur" 
       widgetVar="myTooltip"
       value="Maximum amount has been reached" />
```

Comment: Because the `p:tooltip` has no client side API like `.hide()` it wont work with plain javascript objects. You need to use jQuery objects to make us of the `.hide()` (and `.show()` or `.toggle()´). See [Primefaces Documentation, page 435](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf)